# Pass data from android application to the server

Tags: php, android, json

I need to pass some data from my android application to my PHP server.

This is my code

```
public class BackgroundDataLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{


@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    JSONObject jsObj=new JSONObject();

    try {
        jsObj.put("ID", 1);
        jsObj.put("Name", "Shashika");
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url+"/data.php");


    try {
        StringEntity se=new StringEntity(jsObj.toString());
        se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
        httppost.setEntity(se);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

        JSONArray finalResult = null;
        String json = null;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        String text = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray;
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        // Execute HTTP Post Request

        try {

            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int statusCode=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode==200){

                HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
                text=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            }

            else{

                return "error "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            jsonArray= new JSONArray(text);
            //text=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray(name);
            text=jsonArray.getString(0);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String tag=text;
        Log.d(tag, text);
        return text;

}
```

Now I need to read this data as a JSON object in a php file in my server. How can I read these data in my php file in the server?

Comment: did you make your PHP script as yet

Comment: No, Actually I have no idea that how to do it

Comment: U don't know how to write php scripts?

Comment: Well you seem to have the android side down, so the `data.php` maybe this link can help you some as well http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indeed would be nice if you would focus on the php and not the android code. So you are POSTing your JSON data according to normal HTTP requests, I assume. If not, please state otherwise.

You should be happy with the following code snippet:

```
// get the POSTed data
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

// decode the JSON formatted data
$obj = json_decode($json);

// such that - on success - $obj is either null,true,false, an array or a stdClass object

// assuming you POST {"my_key":"my_value"} you can access this as follows
$obj->my_key == 'my_value'; // -> true

// or if you pass the according Options to json_decode to enforce using associative arrays
$obj['my_key'] == 'my_value'; // ->true
```

Essentially you'll find more details in the official  [PHP JSON documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php), coincidently being the first hit on google with 'php json'.

I further assume you know how to do some basic coding in php.